# Using SSH-LPR with Mac?

Tags: ssh, printing, cups

I'm looking for a way to add a printer to my MacBook that prints using the `lpr` command on a remote server. I have passwordless logins set up, and I found a script that appears to do what I need it to: [SSH-LPR Backend for CUPS](http://www.masella.name/technical/sshlpr.html). The only problem is setting it up.

I figured out that on Mac, `/usr/lib/cups/backend` is actually `/usr/libexec/cups/backend`, and I added, and `chmod`'d the sshlpr script to that folder.

Then I went to `http://localhost:631/` after `cupsctl WebInterface=yes`, but I don't see an option to add an SSH-LPR printer.

What do I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. Turns out all I needed to do was restart the CUPS daemon.
A simple `killall cupsd` followed by refreshing the web interface did the trick.

I got the option to add an "LPR through SSH" printer, and it shows up Print & Scan as well as my applications.